# Analysis Services Tabular 1400 project - not a valid data source - ADLS data source

Tags: visual-studio-2017, azure-data-lake, azure-analysis-services

Since 08 May 2018 there seems to be an issue with Azure Data Lake Store data source using Microsoft Analysis Services Project extension.

We are using ,
Visual Studio 2017 15.7.1
Microsoft Analysis Services Projects 1.26 Extension
Tabular model compatibility level 1400

We get the below error when we try to open the Model.bim from an already existing project.
*The given data source reference is not a valid data source*

[image]

We only have one data source which is an Azure Data Lake Store.

If we click OK and proceed it throws error *This model is already open in another location by the same user, please close the other project before working on this one.*
So we deleted the Model.bim_xx.settings and tried again it throws "….not a valid data source" error

We also tried to create a brand new Analysis Services Project (Tabular model) and tried to do Import from Data Source - then select Azure Data Lake Store - sign in - It connects successfully - doesn't go into Power Query editor 
When click OK - there is nothing under Data Source - in Tabular Model Explorer

If we try anything after clicking OK - VS 2017 crashes.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is acknowledged as an issue in Microsoft Analysis Services Projects Extension version 1.26 - Microsoft are working on it.

Uninstall version 1.26 and re-install 1.25. You may need to request the .vsix file for version 1.25 from extension team. Contact them in the respective Visual Marketplace page.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ProBITools.MicrosoftAnalysisServicesModelingProjects